# Binomial coefficient in python using memoization

Tags: python-3.x

```
def c_b(n, k):
    memo = {}

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    try:
        return memo[n,k]
    except KeyError:
        memo[n, k] = c_b(n-1, k) + c_b(n-1, k-1)
        return memo[n, k]
```

I would like to know why this code does not work properly I did not get any exceptions/errors just some wrong numeric results for example 4 instead of 10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @БогданОпир I did not get any exceptions/errors just some wrong numeric results for example 4 instead of 10.

Comment: `memo = {}` resets `memo` to the empty dictionary each time you call this function.

Comment: You should see what a local variable is, and learn OOP fundamentals. As a quick bodge you can use `global` and `nonlocal` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The variables created inside the function are deleted after each function execution, and even if they were't, they would be overwritten in your case. Here is a quick fix for your case, using `global` keyword:

```
memo = {}

def c_b(n, k):
    global memo

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    try:
        return memo[n,k]
    except KeyError:
        memo[n, k] = c_b(n-1, k) + c_b(n-1, k-1)
        return memo[n, k]
```

Even though this should be working properly, never use this when it comes to code that should be either reliable, developable or even just readable. For those cases basic OOP should be used:

```
class Cb: #  created class [type of objects]
    def __init__(self): #  initialization, runs on object creation
        self.memo = {}

    def c_b(self, n, k): #  in this case, self=cb
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if k == 0:
            return 1
        try:
            return self.memo[n,k]
        except KeyError:
            self.memo[n, k] = self.c_b(n-1, k) + self.c_b(n-1, k-1)
            return self.memo[n, k]

n,k = int(input('n: ')), int(input('k: '))
cb = Cb() #  created new object (cb) of class Cb
result = cb.c_b(n, k) #  called a method c_b of object cb
print(result)
```

Hope that's helpful!